# Does my US fiance need entry clearance to visit me in Wales

Tags: visas, uk, us-citizens

My fiance is planning to visit me in Wales within the next couple of months for a period of 5-6 months. Will he need entry clearance and what are chances of him being turned away?

Comment: He does not need an entry clearance, but his chances of being turned away will be significantly less if he does have one.

Comment: I assume "US fiance" means he is a US citizen.  If not, then please edit the tags to state his citizenship.

Comment: Yes he is a US citizen. Thanks you for the tip with the tag.